# Pushforward of measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have been given the following question:
Let $X = [0, 1]$ and let µ be Lebesgue measure on X. Let $f(x) = x^2$
. Describe the measure
$f∗µ$ ( the pushforward)

a.) by calculating $(f∗µ)([a, b])$ for every interval $[a, b] ⊂ R$
b.) by giving the density of $f∗µ$ with respect to Lebesgue measure.

I tried to solve it , especially part a but for b, I do not undertand how to use definition of density.

for part a I said
 $(f∗µ)([a,b])$ = 0  if $[a,b]∩[0,1] = {c}$ ˝if the intersection is a single point˝ since lesbegue measure of a point is zero.
or $(f∗µ)([a,b])$= $\sqrt{d}-\sqrt{c} \, \, if  [a,b]∩[0,1]=[c,d]$

but for part be I am trying to use Definition of density of measure: Definition 12 (density). If $ν(A) = \int_{A}^{} f dµ$ , we say that
the measure $ν$ has density $f$ with respect to $µ$. should I differentiate $(f∗µ)([a,b])$ in a? any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Hint: To find the density, it is enough to find $g$ such that $\int_0^x g d\mu =(f*\mu)([0,x])=\sqrt{x}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, this is because of the fact, that the family of sets $\{[0,x] \:|\: x \in [0,1]\}$ generates the borel sigma algebra on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint...I think I get the idea now, so will I be done if I say $ g = \frac{1}{2*\sqrt{x}} $? and am I on the right track with part a

Comment: Yes to both.
Although i realize a small mistake in my argument above. Do you need the density with respect to the lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ or the lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ in the latter case you will have to multiply by the indicator function for $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you.the question did not specify